# C# - Selenium - Chromedriver - How to find element in class named the same as another class

Tags: c#, html, .net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have elements:

```
<li class="aaa"><div class='bbb'>..content1</div></li >
<li class="aaa"><div class='bbb'>..content2</div></li >
<li class="aaa"><div class='bbb'>..content3</div></li >
...
<li class="aaa"><div class='bbb'>..content4</div></li >
```

Finding a classes by:

```
var AllClasses= driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("li[class='aaa']"));
```

And then, I'm doing a loop, and trying to check content of specify element:

```
for (int gr = 0; gr <= AllClasses.Count();gr++) 
{
   var NumberMembers = AllClasses[gr].FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='bbb']"));
}
```

But it always find me only "bbb" from the first li class. I think that its searching no in specify li from collection from "FindElements" but in whole document.

Can you tell me what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use div, cause all divs have same classname.

css selector would be :  `div.bbb`

```
var AllClasses= driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.bbb"));  

for (int gr = 0; gr <= AllClasses.Count();gr++) 
{
   var NumberMembers = AllClasses[gr].Text;
   Console.WriteLine(NumberMembers);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but i think that elements from li was found correctly, because every of them has a different ```{Element (id = xxxxxxxxxx)}```

Comment: @Kamil : You haven't posted the id though :) . I think you should give a try to this locator. I have updated the code with print statement.

Comment: a ok im undestand. You suggested to leave alone ```aaa``` and just ```bbb```. Sorry my mistake. Ok i will try it now :)

Comment: Yes, Because all div have same class name.

Comment: Okay, and by the way, can you tell me, what if i have another divs/tags etc. in every ```bbb``` class? Can i manage each of them?

Comment: yes, you can. As long as class name is not changing , you can.